# What's the best way to zoomIN/zoomOUT sortable items and droppable areas?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'd like to know whats the best way to scale sortable items(some of the sortables are droppable areas). If I use the "zoom" function I get huge offsets and sortable stops working.